# Transformation-matrix for square to circle?

Tags: matrices, transformation

I'm striving for a general explanation of integral transformation. So far I've been told some variable substitutions (like polar coordinates) without really getting the gist of it. However I've just got to know a method that makes the whole process pretty clear to me due to matrix multiplication. That method I want to generalize:

[image]

So according to the the rotation transformation above I ask myself whether there exist something alike:

$\left(\begin{array}{cc}x\\y\end{array}\right) = \Phi \cdot \left(\begin{array}{cc}u\\v\end{array}\right)$ in order that $x = u\,\cos(v)\quad y = u\,\sin(v)$. Could it be?

Comment: Here is a former [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159738/complex-transformation-that-transforms-a-square-into-a-circle/3159827#3159827) of mine giving a solution in terms of a certain complex function connectd to elliptic integrals.

Comment: With keywords sequence "mapping circle onto square" Google finds you a lot of references, some of them very simple. The advantage of conformal mapping is angle preservation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix represents a linear transformation. And a linear transformation maps lines onto lines. Hence no linear transformation will have the properties you ask for.

You need to look at other kind of transformations!