# Circlized checkerboard

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, conformal-geometry

The function $\varphi$ defined by
$$
\varphi(z) = \sqrt{i} \, F\bigl(i \sinh^{-1}(\sqrt{i} \, z) \,|\, -1 \bigr).
$$
where $F(z | m)$ is the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind,
maps the unit disk to the square with vertices $C \times (\pm 1 \pm i)$ where
$C = \varphi(1) \approx 0.92703733865...$, and it is
[conformal](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3159827/38217).

I'm trying to use this function to map a checkerboard to a circle.
I'm using this pseudo-code:

```
function colormap(z)
    x = 3 * real(z)
    y = 3 * imag(z)
    out = modulo(x, 2) < 1 ?
        ( modulo(y, 2) < 1 ? "black" : "white" ) :
        ( modulo(y, 2) < 1 ? "white" : "black" )
    return out
end
Z = {0, 0.001, 0.002, ..., 1} x {0, 0.001, 0.002, ..., 1}
for z in Z
    if modulus(z) > 1
        plot( "gray" ) at z
    else
        plot( colormap( phi(z) / 0.92703733865 ) ) at z
```

Here is the result I get:

[image]

I don't understand why the transformed squares at the corners of
the checkerboard have only three sides and not four. Could you help me
to understand? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Each corner square has degenerated into a triangle because three of its vertices lie on the circumference of the circle. The fourth vertex is simply the midpoint of the "base" of the triangle.

Comment: Both external sides of corner square are transformed to arcs at the boundary of circle with exterior, and as they have common point in the corner then after transformation these arcs will have common point. You just see two adjacent arcs as one arc in your picture.